# Flutter VS Code gives Class not found exception

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Visual Studio Code for flutter development and I found one strange issue where it gives compile time error even after I have added import packages.

```
import 'package:session_06_database/model/employee.dart';

Employee employee = new Employee("", "", "", "");
```

At IDE I am not seeing  any error, but if I run this from the terminal like

> flutter run lib/main.dart;

It gives an error

```
Compiler message:                                                       
lib/main.dart:31:3: Error: Type 'Employee' not found.
```

Note: Same code is working on android studio.

Comment: I heard about a similar issue. Try to delete your whole employee.dart file, then recreate it and add it to your classes.

Comment: On the odd occasion VSCode can throw a wobbly. Turn it off and on again. Do a 'flutter clean' for good measure.

Comment: Some weeks ago the same would happen to Android Studio once in a while. After a restart all was good.